# Selecting all Snowflake views by their size

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to select all views in a database/schema in snowflake Snowflake along with their respective sizes so that I can find the largest views?  Either bytes or rowcount is sufficient.

I am only seeing NULLs in information_schema.tables.bytes and information_schema.tables.rowcount.  Also, information_schema.table_storage_metrics is empty:

```
SELECT table_name, row_count
FROM   snowflake.account_usage.tables
WHERE  table_catalog = 'DB'
AND    table_schema = 'SCHEMA'
AND    table_type = 'VIEW'
AND    deleted IS NULL
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: You would need ACCOUNTADMIN to see data in table_storage_metrics. I’m guessing it’s also a privileges issue if you can’t see data in the TABLES view. Have you tried ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES?

Comment: @NickW I just switched to ACCOUNTADMIN and had the same result.  Query attached.

Comment: Sorry, missed the bit in your question where you said you were querying information about views, not tables. Views don’t contain any records so the record rowcount/size will always be null (just realised you edited your question to change from tables to views - so I didn’t miss it :) )

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do this other than executing dynamic SQL to insert result scans of `explain select * from t;` for all the views to a temp table and looking at `bytesAssigned` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a "view" is always 0 - views contain no data.

As Kath comment says, the closest you could get to "size of a view" is running it (as in `select * from view`) and counting how many bytes come out of executing that query.

Another alternative is following the dependencies of that view until you find all the tables backing it, and then adding the size of those tables. But a view might contain way more data or way less data than the tables that it's bringing it's data from.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/user-guide/object-dependencies#label-object-dependencies-view-query